# Windows 10 IoT loop GPIO in background

Tags: c#, windows, iot

I'm new to Windows 10 IoT. I've been working with microcontrollers for several years, and maybe it's my bad habits. I'm building an application which needs to "ping" several GPIO until a specific combination is found between them. Once found, a graphical interface should do an animation.

My problem is as follow: What is the best way to continuos loop in the background while showing the graphical interface?

I'm currently doing as follow:

InitGPIO();

```
timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0.05);
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
if (init)
   timer.Start();
```

and

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
      //Here I loop the GPIO. I f a comkbination is found, the graphical interface is triggered.
}
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably best not to attach yourself to a timer specifically because many sensors and controllers will have their own polling rates, and the GpioPin has its own event receiver for handling when the value changes.

If you bind everything to event receivers, then in your main program class you can simply loop `while(true) {}` after everything is initialized.

Because I'm only writing small projects for testing, and I often get up from my desk and forget to power off my raspi, I bake in a timeout to my loop so it automatically shuts off after 5 minutes.

```
var timeout = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);

while (DateTime.Now < timeout) {
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}
```

This will check every second if it's passed the timeout. A habit I got from playing around in Unity development (which also uses the while(true) concept) is to not actually let a loop run at max speed as it may end up chewing up CPU cycles. It's better to throw in even a simple 1 ms delay to an empty loop.